# Angular Kendo scheduler refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I have a kendo-angular scheduler as follows:

```
var kendoDataSource = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
    schema: {
        model: {
            fields: {
                id:{defaultValue:2}
            } 
        }
    },
});


$scope.schedulerOptions = {
    date: new Date(),
    height: 450,
    views: ["day", "week", "month", "agenda"],
    editable: { template: $("#editor").html() },
    dataSource: {
        batch: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://192.168.1.121:8000/pp/getevent/"+$rootScope.selectedstud.pk,
                dataType: "json"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and my html is as follows:

```
<div kendo-scheduler="grid" k-options="schedulerOptions" id="schedule">
     <span k-event-template class='custom-event'>{{dataItem.title}}</span>
     <div k-all-day-event-template class='custom-all-day-event'>{{dataItem.title}}</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to refresh the data inside the grid based on a selection which i am passing in the read(). How do i do this?

Comment: In your dataSource defintition, include the data option as a js function. It should return an object for your datasource url parameter. $scheduler.data("kendoScheduler").dataSource.read();

Comment: somehow when i put my transport inside the datasource outside the options, it is not fetching my data!

Comment: Is it not including the read parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It will be along the lines of this setup. I haven't tested it, but it should work. When you call the read method, it will include the data function return object. Good luck.

```
$scope.schedulerOptions = {
date: new Date(),
height: 450,
views: ["day", "week", "month", "agenda"],
editable: { template: $("#editor").html() },
dataSource: {
    batch: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://192.168.1.121:8000/pp/getevent/"+$rootScope.selectedstud.pk,
            dataType: "json",
            data: "additionalParams"
        }
    }
}
};

function addtionalParams(){ return { param1: 1, param1: 2}; }
```